# Objective c: Tab bar not showing up

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I've followed [Programmatically creating tab bar for ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038979/programmatically-creating-tab-bar-for-viewcontroller) and [How can I create a tab view programmatically on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920305/how-can-i-create-a-tab-view-programmatically-on-ios) to try and create a tab bar programmatically in my ViewController using objective c, but my tab bar doesn't show up. Here is my code in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [FIRApp configure];
    self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    viewController.title =@"Home";
    UINavigationController *nav =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController, nil];
    [viewController release];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];

    // Put the tabBarController's view on the window.
    [self.window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

    
    return YES;
}
```

There are no errors, the tab bar just doesn't show up

Comment: Just remove these code: [viewController release] and [self.window addSubview:[tabBarController view]]

Comment: I've tried out your suggestion but it still does not appear. However I put the same code into SceneDelegate.m instead and it appeared, so maybe its due to the newer Xcode version I am using?

Answer (score 0):

I come from Swift, try to learn some Objective-C stuff. I plan to create a Youtube clone app to practice my OC skill.

`sceneDelegate` is come when Apple published iOS 13. That change apply on both `Swift` and `OC`. What is `sceneDelegate` used for? See [difference-between-scenedelegate-and-appdelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56498306/10158398).

```
- (void)scene:(UIScene *)scene willConnectToSession:(UISceneSession *)session options:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions {
    UIWindowScene *windowScene = (UIWindowScene*) scene;
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    
    UITabBarController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    
    _window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    _window.windowScene = windowScene;
}
```

Instead declare UITabBarController in SceneDelegate, I create a UIViewController subclassed UITbarBarController, because I need this class to do some extra job, like `dependency injection`.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configTabBar];
    
}

- (void)configTabBar {
    UIViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *exploreVC = [[ExploreViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *subscriptionVC = [[SubscriptionViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *libraryVC = [[LibraryViewController alloc] init];
    
    UINavigationController *vc1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeVC];
    UINavigationController *vc2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:exploreVC];
    UINavigationController *vc3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:subscriptionVC];
    UINavigationController *vc4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:libraryVC];
    [self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4, nil]];
    vc1.title = home;
    vc2.title = explore;
    vc3.title = sub;
    vc4.title = library;
}


@end
```

Well, it works but I'm not sure if it is the best practice. In 2021, Objective-C learning materials is rare stuff in the internet. I could find 10 Swift tutorials but not 1 OC.